# Difference between attrMap and attrs in beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to know whats the difference between `attrMap` and `attrs` in [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)? To be more specific, which tags have `attrs` and which have `attrMap`?

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(source)
>>> tag = soup.find(name='input')
>>> dict(tag.attrs)['type']
u'text'
>>> tag.attrMap['type']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `attrMap` field is an internal field in the `Tag` class. You should not use it in your code. You should instead use

```
value = tag[key]
tag[key] = value
```

This maps internally to `tag.attrMap[key]`, but only after `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` have made sure to initialize `self.attrMap`. This is done in `_getAttrMap`, which is nothing by a complicated `dict(self.attrs)` call. So for your code you'll use

```
>>> url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842224/"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
>>> soup.find(name='input')
>>> tag = soup.find(name='input')
>>> tag['type']
u'text'
```

If you want to check for the existance of a given attribute, then you must use

```
try:
    tag[key]
    # found key
except KeyError:
    # key not present
```

or

```
if key in dict(tag.attrs):
    # found key
else:
    # key not present
```

As pointed out by Adam, this is because the `__contains__` method on `Tag` searches the content, not the attributes, and so the more familiar `key in tag` doesn't do what you would expect. This complexity arises because BeautifulSoup handles HTML tags with repeated attributes. So a normal map (dictionary) isn't quite enough since the keys can be duplicated. But if you want to check if there is *any* key with a given name, then `key in dict(tag.attrs)` will do the right thing.

Comment: Great Answer. Another question related to this -
How do I know if an attribute is present?

From the above example, I could do - 
tag.has_key('type')

but after running PEP8 against the code, it says has_key has been deprecated and use 'in' instead? Any thoughts? I can't do tag.keys()?!

Comment: So: 'if "type" in tag: whatever()'

Comment: @AdamKG - Yes!! But doing the same returns False. So "if 'type' in tag:whatever()" does not work :(

Comment: So you mean 'assert "type" not in tag; assert tag["type"] == "text"' doesn't raise any assertion errors? EDIT: just tried it, apparently so. That's weird behavior on BeautifulSoup's part...

Comment: So just go ahead and use .has_key() - it's not PEP8-compliant, but BeautifulSoup isn't properly emulating a dictionary here - \_\_contains\_\_ (what's called for the 'in' operator) checks against self.contents instead of the attributes.

Comment: Ya...
`>>> assert tag['type'] == 'text'
>>> assert 'type' not in tag
>>> `
don't throw error.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a bit about how to search for keys (attributes) in the tags.