# Extracting the value of a key with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall, getattr

I want to extract the value of the "archivo" key of something like this:

```
...
<applet name="bla" code="Any.class" archive="Any.jar">
<param name="abc" value="space='1' archivo='bla.jpg'" </param>
<param name="def" value="space='2' archivo='bli.jpg'" </param>
<param name="jkl" value="space='3' archivo='blu.jpg'" </param>
</applet>
...
```

I suppose I need a list with [bla.jpg, bli.jpg, ...], so I try options like:

```
inputTag = soup.findAll("param",{'value':'archivo'})
```

or

```
inputTag = soup.findAll(attrs={"value" : "archivo"})
```

or

```
inputTag = soup.findAll("archivo")
```

and always I get an empty list: []

#### Other unsuccessful options:

```
inputTag = soup.findAll("param",{"value" : "archivo"}.contents)
```

I get something like: a dict object hasn't attribute contents

```
inputTag = unicode(getattr(soup.findAll('archivo'), 'string', ''))
```

I get nothing.

Finally I have seen: [Difference between attrMap and attrs in beautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842224/difference-between-attrmap-and-attrs-in-beautifulsoup), and:

```
for tag in soup.recursiveChildGenerator():
    print tag['archivo']
```

find nothing, it must be tag of *name*, *code* or *archive* keys.

#### and more finally:

```
tag.attrs = [(key,value) for key,value in tag.attrs if key == 'archivo']
```

but tag.attrs find nothing

---

OK, with jcollado's help I could get the list this way:

```
imageslist = []
patron = re.compile(r"archivo='([\w\./]+)'")
for tag in soup.findAll('param'):
    if patron.search(tag['value']):
        imageslist.append(patron.search(tag['value']).group(1))
```

Comment: You're xml looks strange, are you sure it's `value="space='1' archivo='bla.jpg'"` and not something like `value="" space='1' archivo='bla.jpg'`?

Comment: I have simplified it, really there are lines like: <param name="G_05" value="espacio='pregunta' tipo='imagen' dibujar-si='(tipopre[pactual]=2)&(nrep[pactual]>=1)&((corregir)|(verresp)|(~modificar))' expresi&oacute;n='(75,140)' archivo='../imagenes/Ac.jpg' coord_abs='si'">

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `archivo` isn't an attribute of `param`, but something inside the `value` attribute. To extract `archivo` from `value`, I suggest to use a regular expression as follows:

```
>>> archivo_regex = re.compile(r"archivo='([\w\./]+)'")
>>> [archivo_regex.search(tag['value']).group(1)
... for tag in soup.findAll('param')]
[u'bla.jpg', u'bli.jpg', u'blu.jpg']
```

Comment: ¿? if I try to create the list with: [archivo_regex.search(tag['value']).group(1) for tag in soup.findAll('param')] then I get <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: That means that the regular expression didn't match as expected. From the comment above, I see you need also the slash character. I've edited my answer with it.

Comment: the problem go on, perhaps I simplified too much the code, here it is the site (severals image files, you see): http://descartes.cnice.mec.es/heda/ASIPISA/ASIPISA_M/unidades/escalera/escalera.html' . The code stoped showing tag = <param name="nombre" value="Escalera"> </param> (thaks for your time)

Comment: perhaps the error is just because not always "value" has "archivo".

Comment: neither "archivo" is always in the same position, I see my example was very bad

Comment: I'm not able to open the web page because of permissions problems (even after removing the trailing `'`), so unless you provide a more complete example I won't be able to help. Sorry.

Comment: sorry... http://descartes.cnice.mec.es/heda/ASIPISA/ASIPISA_M/unidades/escalera/escalera.html, is OK?